# Best solution for 8 different np.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I plan to add three more np.where conditions to the code below. I have a feeling that there's a more efficient way to achieve my goal of calculations conditional to a column value. What's the best solution here? The .map function below did not seem to work either.

```
ddata['BustPx']= np.where((ddata['Session'] == 'Regular'),np.where((ddata['Side'] == 'BUY'),ddata['TxnBidPx']-ddata['LastPx'],ddata['LastPx']-ddata['TxnAskPx']),np.where((ddata['Side'] == 'BUY'),ddata['ClosePx']-ddata['LastPx'],ddata['ClosePx']-ddata['TxnAskPx']))
```

Comment: See Logical Operations: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html

Comment: Another option is [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)